# Want to install GDB on Fedora 7 machine

Tags: sudo, gdb

I want to **install GDB GNU debugger** for debugging C Programs, onto my fedora machine..

I installed the gzip file from gnu website, but it gives error during MAKE command.. I am doing all the steps correctly which reading from the readme file, and tutorial on internet. Please guide.

Also i am trying to do from `yum install gdb` command and `sudo apt-get install gdb`,

yum is not found in my system, i installed it, but now it is giving some unusual error, some file missing.. So no success with this..

sudo apt-get is working, but it is also giving some following errorss...

```
[oracle@localhost Programs]$ sudo apt-get install gdb
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
oracle is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
[oracle@localhost Programs]$ sudo apt-get install gdb
```

I am in real nead of this gdb tool.. how to go about it.. Please share your experiences over this..

Thankx..

Comment: 7? Are you *trying* to get everyone to point and laugh?

Comment: Why sayingg soo... 

i am laughing at me fr past 4 days.. that i am not able to install gdb, a simple tool.. after so much reading of the articles and stuff....

Comment: Unless you have a really, really burning need to run Fedora 7, you should consider moving to a supported version of Fedora, or at least to something like CentOS.

Comment: Now plz tell me to change the Linux version.. i have alreadyy grilled my head down to install oracle on different linux version, and got success in one.. Plz tell me the way out to install gdb on this machine, if there is anyy??

Comment: Anywayz thanx for that suggestionn.. But plzz any other alternative availablee.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bite. Some points:

- yum should be available by default in Fedora, if it is not, there is something wrong. Did you try starting it as root?
- apt-get is (usually) only used to manage debian based distributions (Debian, Ubuntu primarily), not rpm based like Fedora
- If something essential like yum is missing, you'll have nearly no chance to install it afterwards (from source?) and get it actually working as excpected.
- The error messaging *oracle is not in the sudoers file.* has a meaning, you know? The user oracle is not allowed to use sudo in the first place, so this can't work.

What version of Oracle are you trying to install that will work on Fedora 7, but not a current one?

And really, before you continue with managing heavyweights like Oracle, you should try to learn about the fundamentals in a systematic approach. Asking google "how to install gbd" will help you only if you understand the basics.